# Publishing a shiny/leaflet map made in R to a website

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm helping a friend doing some research on the number of breweries in CT. With help from this community I was able to make a map of breweries in leaflet and was able to add a slider using shiny. Now I want to be able to give my friend the map so he can add it to the website where he is publishing his research. I'm new to some of this and was wondering if anybody had some ideas for me. Here is the code (thanks to Ben) I used to make the map:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(bottom = 30, right = 10,
                textOutput("Counter"),
                sliderInput("Year", "Year", 1990, 2000, value = 1995, step = 1, sep = "")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sliderData <- reactive({
    breweries_subset %>%
      filter(YearOpened <= input$Year)
  })

  output$Counter <- renderText(
    paste("Number Breweries: ", nrow(sliderData()))
  )

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(min(breweries_subset$Longitude), min(breweries_subset$Latitude),
                max(breweries_subset$Longitude), max(breweries_subset$Latitude))
  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", data = sliderData()) %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        addProviderTiles(provider = 'Esri.WorldStreetMap') %>%
        addAwesomeMarkers(icon = beer_icon,
                          group = 'Breweries',
                          popup = ~ Name)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**

I took your suggestions and tried publishing to shinyapps.io. Here's the code I used:

For ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
    absolutePanel(bottom = 30, right = 10,
                  textOutput("Counter"),
                  sliderInput("Year", "Year", 1990, 2019, value = 1995, step = 1, sep = "")
    )
)
```

And for server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(fontawesome)
library(rsconnect)
function(input, output, session) {
    ct_breweries <- read.csv('ct_breweries.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
    sliderData <- reactive({
        ct_breweries %>%
            filter(YearOpened <= input$Year)
    })
    output$Counter <- renderText(
        paste('Number of Breweries: ', nrow(sliderData()))
    )
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            fitBounds(min(ct_breweries$Longitude), min(ct_breweries$Latitude),
                      max(ct_breweries$Longitude), max(ct_breweries$Latitude))
    })
    observe({
        leafletProxy('map', data = sliderData()) %>%
            clearMarkers() %>%
            addProviderTiles(provider = 'Esri.WorldStreetMap') %>%
            addAwesomeMarkers(icon = beer_icon,
                              group = 'Breweries',
                              popup = ~ Name)
    })
}
```

It works fine locally. When I try to publish it, I get a Disconnected from Server error. In the logs it says something about 'YearOpened' not found. There's definitely a column for that in the .csv. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the call to the fall. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You might want to read about ways to deploy a `shiny` app [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/).

Comment: If you don't mind to host your app/data on an external site, the most straightforward way would be to upload your app on shinyapps.io and mirror it in your webpage through an <iframe>

Comment: If you keep the map simple enough you can download an html version with markers and selectors, etc. library(leaflet)
m=leaflet()%>%addTiles()
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(m, file="m.html")

Comment: Thanks everyone. I finally got it to work by adding a global.R file to the deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding all the package loading and dataset reading to a `global.R` file (in the same app folder) as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(fontawesome)
library(rsconnect)

ct_breweries <- read.csv('ct_breweries.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

You can then remove these from `ui.R` and `server.R`.

The problem seems to be that the dataset is not visible to the server - this should fix that. Also, make sure that the csv file is in the same folder.

**Update**

Based on my comment above, if this is sufficient, you can just save an html file of the map that you can send to your friend to open in a browser. I have attempted to write the code without your data so this may not work.

```
library(leaflet)
library(fontawesome)
library(htmlwidgets)

ct_breweries <- read.csv('ct_breweries.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')

leaflet_map <- leaflet(data = ct_breweries) %>%
    addProviderTiles(provider = 'Esri.WorldStreetMap') %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(icon = beer_icon,
                      group = ~ YearOpened,
                      popup = ~ Name) %>%
    addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = 1990:2000,
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
    ) %>% hideGroup(~ YearOpened)

saveWidget(leaflet_map, file="leaflet_map.html")
```

It does lose the slider option - replaced with checkboxes. You can remove the `hideGroup()` and `collapsed = FALSE` to see other options. This might be easier assuming the slider is not a requirement.

This file is saved offline but you will need an internet connection to fetch the leaflet map tiles.